# C# ASP.net MVC Reading and writing to SQL (Connecting frontend with backend)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sqlite

I am fairly new to programming, but do have some experience as i have created a few small apps previously.

The problem I am facing with my first "larger" application i connecting the SQL data access and the front-end.
I have not been able to find how to do this with SQLite. Microsoft SQL seems to be more common, but following these guides gives a new person like me more confusion then explanation how to complete the task.

If someone could lead me to a guide or maybe explain to me how it works and should be done. Link to the project -> https://github.com/FredrikJamshidi/On-OffBoarding

Comment: In this case google will be a better friend than SO. Even SQLite web site has C# examples.

Comment: The problem is that I *know* how to do this in a simple console app.
But not in ASP.net MVC..